# How to add to each column of dataframe value from named vector?

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got a dataframe df.

```
df <- data.frame(c(4,4,4,4,4,4), c(0,0,0,0,0,0))
colnames(df) <- c("a", "b")
```

```
> df
     a   b
1    4   0
2    4   0
3    4   0
4    4   0
5    4   0
6    4   0
```

And a named vector v, where names are corresponding to column names in my data frame.

```
v <- c(0.04, 0.01)
names(v) <- c("a", "b")
```

```
> v
      a       b 
   0.04    0.01
```

There can be many columns in my dataframe and vector will always have corresponding names.

I want to add to each element of my column value from corresponding vector so I get result like this:

```
> df
     a      b
1    4.04   0.01
2    4.04   0.01
3    4.04   0.01
4    4.04   0.01
5    4.04   0.01
6    4.04   0.01
```

How can I do this with dplyr?
All I've come up so far is

```
df %>% mutate_all(. = . + v[.])
```

But this gives me an error.

```
Error in mutate_all(., . = . + v[.]) : 
  argument 2 matches multiple formal arguments
```

The problem is I don't know how to point that corresponding column should be changed by corresponding vector.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `base R` (assuming the columns are in the same order)

```
df + v[col(df)]
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
map2_df(df, v[names(df)], `+`)
```

---

NOTE: the `mutate_all` loops through the columns of 'df', but it is not the case with 'v'.  There is no index to select 'v' element that corresponds to the column in 'df' using `mutate_all`

Comment: Better `df[names(v)]<-Map("+",df[names(v)],v)`. You fail here if the vector names and dataframe names are in different order.

Comment: I knew this would be simple but didn't expect it to be that simple. Thank you.
Is there any way that we can pipe it like in my example?

Comment: @АндрійzOFsky  You can do `df %>% map2_df(v[names(df)], "+")`

Answer (score 0):

This should work as a general case:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  tibble(
    a = rep(4, 6),
    b = rep(0, 6)
  )

v <- c(0.04, 0.01)
names(v) <- c("a", "b")

v_df <- 
  v %>% 
  enframe() %>% 
  transmute(name, v_value = value)

df %>% 
  gather(key = name, value = value, a:b) %>% 
  left_join(v_df, by = "name") %>% 
  transmute(name, new_value = value + v_value)
```

Then you can re-spread out the data if you want it returned to the original format.